# value |@| is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[String]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to use Scalaz's applicative builder to simplify some code that runs a few futures in parallel:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val fooF: Future [String] = myService.getFoo ()
val barF: Future [String] = myService.getBar ()
val resultF = for {
  foo <- fooF
  bar <- barF
}
yield { foo + bar }
```

I understand that I should be able to rewrite the code above like so:

```
val resultF = (myService.getFoo () |@| myService.getBar ()) {
  (foo, bar) => { foo + bar }
}
```

However I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
value |@| is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[String]
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: which Futures? the scala futures? the scalaz futures? something else? If the scala futures, then what version of scalaz? older versions of scalaz didn't have scala.concurrent.Future typeclass instances and you had to import the scalaz-contrib library for them.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have implicit ExecutionContext in scope, it's required to build Applicative for Future (and also Monad etc)

```
  import scalaz._, Scalaz._

  import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val fooF: Future [String] = Future("aaa")
  val barF: Future [String] = Future("bbb")

  val result = (fooF |@| barF)((l, r) => s"$l$r")

  println(Await.result(result, 10.seconds))
```

**Update**

You can check it in scalaz.std.Future.scala

```
implicit def futureInstance(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Monad[Future] with Cobind[Future] =
    new FutureInstance
```

Comment: I do have an implicit execution context in scope.

Comment: what version of scalaz do you use? Monad for Future available only since scalaz 7.1

Comment: that could be it: 7.0.5

Comment: See scalaz-contrib 0.1.5 (https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/blob/v0.1.5/scala210/main/scala/Future.scala) for `scala.concurrent.Future` monad definition pre scalaz 7.1.

Comment: You may want to double check that `Applicative[Future]` definition behaves like you want with respect to serial vs parallel evaluation when bumping scalaz versions. There's been some debate on scalaz mailing list over the correct behavior. I don't remember what the final consensus was. You best bet is to look at the source, but here is the thread I'm thinking of  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/IuFfWJIXXTo